# Should an RSS feed of hot network questions feed any chat room(s) here?

Tags: discussion, chat, hot-questions

We’ve had the beginnings of a discussion on how the community here would like to handle hot network questions.

- [Should a Question Ever be Removed from Hot Network Questions](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/)

I set up a [temporary room to test the feed and it worked well, except for a bot deleted (or attempted to delete) the room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/92126/2019/4/15/0-17) since RSS doesn’t seem to count as “activity”.

I propose we make a room where people chat to discuss these or use the main room to host this feed.

Please voice a strong “NO - please don’t do this” if you feel that’s correct. Please vote for a “YES - in the main room, please” answer or propose a room if we want to try another side-room that people would hop into regularly to prevent a robotic freeze/deletion.

**Note:** *Upvote* your choice only, no need to downvote the other one.  We will try to keep the current separate room functional, but can take it down if there is a clear winner in the several choices below.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** —— the feed is useful in a separate room reserved for the feed and discussion about the questions, please.

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92126/hotness

Answer (score 2):

**YES** -- in the main room, please

Answer (score 1):

**NO** -- please don't do this anywhere. (We don’t need a feed)

Answer (score 1):

**YES** -- in the main room, please

I don't see a reason, not to put in the main room.

A separate room means that someone has to prevent freezing every 14 days.  This is a bit of an inconvenience and can lead to someone forgetting or getting lazy, which apparently, has happened before.

Currently the main chat isn't very active. New messages are posted once every couple of hours. The feed posts once every couple of hours also. So I don't think the feed is going to crowd the main chat room to interrupt someones conversation.

Other sites have a feeds in their main chat rooms. (e.g. Stack Overflow, many of the language chat rooms have feeds without a separate room).

Comment: But the freezing problem is solved by having *conscripted an automated bot* for the separate room! No AskD human user is needed any longer for anti-freeze activity. (And participation is hopefully increasing a bit in both rooms? ;)

Comment: @LangLangC I don't understand. Is the feed, enough to prevent freeze?

Comment: No. The feeds don't count and are useless for that. We tried that and it failed, quickly. But the user GenericBot is our bouncer: always present, monitoring activity, and after 5 days of no-shows and no activity, he posts a short no-freezer, fully automated. *He* is enough to prevent freezing. Good guy.